override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) { Needs explanation
Within my application the next action is initiated when the interstitial add is dismissed
override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    // Called when ad is dismissed.
    Log.d(TAG, "Ad dismissed fullscreen content.")
    mInterstitialAd = null
     getNextItem()
  }

getNextItem() is the function that continues the play.
My question is this :
Do  I add getNextItem() to the code in the following function?
override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to load")
mInterstitialAd = null
 }

I cannot understand how the play will continue. If the interstitial ad fails to load. The code in written in  override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() will not be called.


Create a function playAnyway and put all codes inside onAdDismissedFullScreenContent().

fun playAnyway() {
    // codes from onAdDismissedFullScreenContent()
}


Call playAnyway() function in both onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() and onAdFailedToLoad().

override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
    playAnyway()
}

override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
    mInterstitialAd = null
    playAnyway()
}

